# QMainWindow not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arm64, qt6, qmainwindow

using the following configuration

- VM: Debian 12 ARM64
- IDE: Visual Studio Code
- Compiler: g++ 12.2
- Framework: Qt6

I created my first source example in Qt6 with the following code

**CMakeLists.txt (New version)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Test2 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6")

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

qt_add_executable(Test2 MANUAL_FINALIZATION ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(Test2 PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)

qt_finalize_executable(Test2)
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

during compilation, the error appears

> QMainWindow: File or directory does not exist

> ```
>  4 | #include <QMainWindow>
>    | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> compilation terminated.

can you help me ?
Thank you all

My first example in Qt6

Comment: Is your `mainwindow.h`, `cpp`, and `ui` necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please simplify your `CMakeLists.txt`, remove all the android/macos noise, leave out only simple and necessary commands: `find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)`, then `target_link_libraries(YOUR_EXEC PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)` and tell us if it still doesn't work. On normal system, like Debian, this should compile out of the box.

Comment: Thanks pptaszni,I edited the CMakelists.txt file but it still gives the error

Comment: Looks fine, try to debug your cmake: `get_target_property(WidgetsIncl Qt6::Widgets INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)`, and then `message(STATUS "WidgetsIncl: ${WidgetsIncl}")`. Try the same with other [Properties on targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets). You can also try to set `Qt6_ROOT` instead of modifying directly `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Also make sure that the file `QMainWindow` actually exists in your QT installation dir. Maybe one of those things will give you some hint.